Difference result between stripplot and barplot in catplot
I have this code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

%matplotlib inline

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
sns.set_theme()

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lokalhangatt/stackoverlow/refs/heads/main/airbnb_nyc_2019.csv")
df.fillna({'reviews_per_month':0}, inplace=True) #inplace=True 

I want to show that for each room_type, the price in Manhattan is the highest compared to other neighborhood_group. If I wrangle the data with this code:
df.groupby(['neighbourhood_group'])['minimum_nights'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)

>> out[]: 
neighbourhood_group
Manhattan        185833
Brooklyn         121761
Queens            29358
Bronx              4976
Staten Island      1802
Name: minimum_nights, dtype: int64

df.groupby(['room_type', 'neighbourhood_group'])['price'].sum()
>>> out[]:
room_type        neighbourhood_group
Entire home/apt  Bronx                    48325
                 Brooklyn               1704633
                 Manhattan              3289707
                 Queens                  308218
                 Staten Island            30597
Private room     Bronx                    43546
                 Brooklyn                775099
                 Manhattan               932111
                 Queens                  241983
                 Staten Island            11711
Shared room      Bronx                     3588
                 Brooklyn                 20868
                 Manhattan                42709
                 Queens                   13666
                 Staten Island              517
Name: price, dtype: int64

If I plot the data with this code:
sns.catplot(data=df, 
            kind='strip', 
            x='neighbourhood_group', 
            y='price',
            col='room_type', 
            hue='neighbourhood_group', 
            col_wrap=3,
            palette='deep', 
            order=sorted(df.neighbourhood_group.unique()),
            col_order=sorted(df.room_type.unique()),
            sharex=False
            )
plt.show()

It shows the plot like this:

But if I change to kind='bar', it'll show something like this:

I am just confused about why it shows the difference in price result in the y-axis. And if I want to use the barplot, is it possible to adjust the y-axis to the real price as shown in the code above?

If you look at the raw data, 99% of the price observations are between 0 and 500. When creating the bar-plot, the averages are calculated for each group and that is what is displayed. The strip-plot shows the individual observations, where we see a few observations with very high prices and many clumped together near the bottom of the plot. Depending on the purpose of the plots, you could try using a log-scale on the strip-plot.

You can also add an alpha to the strip plot, such that prices which are present more in the dataset will show stronger (e.g. alpha=-1).  Note that the bars by default show the average, and their error bars the "mean of the average" (estimated via "bootstrapping"). See also seaborn's error bars for more options.
